# Why is ([str length] - 2) larger than 0 when str is nil?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

When the follow code is run it goes inside the for loop and run NSLog. Why does this happen?

```
NSString *aString = nil;

for (int i=0; i<([aString length]-2); i++) {
   NSLog(@"Inside loop.");
}
```

As i figure `[aString length]-2` results in -2 and that's less then 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be more precise, `-[NSString length]` returns an unsigned integer, so subtracting two from zero (remember, calling any method on `nil` gives you zero) doesn't give you -2, it gives you a very, very large number. Cast it to an `int` (or an `NSInteger`) to get the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the for loop to run if `i<-2`; as `[NSString length]` returns an **unsigned integer**, this value will wrap round to max int - 2.

You're passing a message to a nil object there too: `[aString length]`. I'm not sure this is defined behaviour, and may return a strange range of values, though I suspect it may be clever enough to return 0. My commentators say that this suspicion is true.

Comment: If `([aString length] - 2)` is -2 (which it is not) then `0 < -2` is false and the loop won't run. It does run, according to the poster.

Comment: Messaging `nil` in Objective-C safely returns zero (and always has) unless the return type is a struct, in which case you may have problems. Even that is fixed in more modern compilers.

Comment: The thing is that int x = [aString length]-2; for(int i=0; i<x;i++){... works and it doesn't jump into the loop.

Comment: The result would be max int - 1 since 0u - 1 = max int.

Comment: @Olof because by assigning it to a variable of type in your are implicitly casting it from unsigned int to signed int.